# Regex for rejecting specified strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have to use asp.net RegularexpressionValidator to validate input from textbox. I want to reject strings that start with `"My Links"` or `"My Urls"` I have used this

```
   ^(?!My Links|My Urls)$
```

but this rejects everything. How should I write this?

Comment: What exactly should be rejected? If you really want to reject My Links|My Urls then do a string compare directly, as it is a const string

Comment: as I said I have to use RegularExpressionvalidator so no other choice.

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls show us your code..

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to reject all strings that start with `My Links` or `My Urls`, then you can use lookaheads, but only if you remove the `$` at the end, or only the empty string will match:

```
^(?!My Links|My Urls)
```

works as expected.

Comment: But my guess was that .* will reject strings if it contains My Link|My Url but I need to reject stand alone My Link and MY Url..

Comment: `My Links sadf` rejected this string

Comment: Sorry I did not understand the `$` what it does here? the last is for the end of line but did not understand the first one

Comment: '^(?!My Links$|My Questions$|My Answers$).*$' used this peice but still saving 'My Links ssss'

Comment: which `$`? at the very end?

Comment: I've rewritten my answer - I hope the misunderstanding is now cleared up.

Comment: it again is rejecting everything

Comment: How *exactly*  are you using this? Please post the *entire* code (in your question, not in a comment).

Comment: ValidationExpression="^(?!My Links|My Questions|My Answers).*"

Comment: If i remove the .*  then it does not except anything

Comment: I think it let me undetstand where to mess with this expression and where not... though I must have to reread this regex because it is quite confusing.